# Expand/Collapse jQuery Accordion at runtime

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I have wrapped a couple of `divs` inside, jQuery Accordian.

JS Code:

```
function MakeAccordian() {
    jQuery("#accordian").accordion(
    {
        heightStyle: "content",
        collapsible: true
    });
}
```

Where `accordian` is the id of parent div.

At runtime, how can I expand/collapse div section inside accodion.

Comment: Some Html can help us understand better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/) is the API documentation. Basically you change the active option:

```
var index = 1; // Opens the second panel
               // If collapsible is true collapses all the rest
$('#accordian').accordion('option', 'active', index);
```

Setting `active` to `false` would collapse all panels but requires collapsible to be true.